# list all files and make them downloadable in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

I am looking to list all of the files in a directory in a browser and allow my users to download them similar to an FTP Client.  I am not looking to allow them to upload via this interface, just select 1 or as many files as they like and download them - kinda like a 1 sided in browser FTP client.

Anyone know of a component for this or a tutorial?

Comment: Generally SO works best if trying something first :-)

Comment: well I can easily list files and provide single links to those files but I am trying to avoid this.  My understanding was this was a question and answer site where we can learn from others previous experience and gain insight from their experience. thanks for the down vote

Comment: Well, yes and no. This question is worded in a very poor manner that does not isolate the "real" issue. In any case, only *one* file content disposition can be sent per reply from the server; and each file content disposition likely involves user interaction (so using trickery to invoke multiple requests is likely to just be annoying).

Comment: My recommendation is then to *zip all the requested files* into a single download and serving that up to the user. Modern desktops (e.g. Windows 7/Vista, OS X) support opening/browsing ZIP files relatively easily.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using IIS, you just need to enable Directory Listing.  I don't think you should need to write any code.

Comment: yeah, I thought about that but it doesn't really give me the nice UI I want - that is just a simple list and would force them to download things 1 by 1 plus there is no security involved.